# Mapzen buildings polygons are clipped when draw on map

Tags: mapzen

I have been using the Mapzen Vector Tile Service
. When I request a certain area I get different results.

hxxps://tile.mapzen.com/mapzen/vector/v1/all/18/214238/114415.json?api_key=[my_key]

Note: that my key is muted.

[This is from mapzen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdh3u.png)

[This is from my server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrGbP.png)

They are both called with the same parameter `18/214238/114415.json`, however the request from my server have my buildings clipped.

I want the builds to be not clipped, I have tested that a building is bounded to 1 tile, if it is larger than the tile it will be clipped. However Mapzen servers seems to not getting the clip issue so I am guessing there is something wrong with my settings.

What setting am I missing? Is there any setting from tileserver,tileqeue or vectordata-source I am missing?

Comment: JSON from mapzen server https://pastebin.com/LTftfDyw
JSON from my server https://pastebin.com/9tbx74ZV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suspect you're using master of all the Tilezen repos instead of the latest tagged releases. The recommended production combo is documented in the release notes here (this is what's used in Mapzen's production stack today):

https://github.com/tilezen/vector-datasource/releases/tag/v1.4.0-docs1

Using v1.4.0 the `clip_factor` should be respected. But that is currently not supported in master due to some large refactoring that's on-going. We may add it back to solve some landuse kind intersection bugs we're seeing, but that work is not yet scheduled.

If you want to hack on master yourself the relevant clip to expand is here:

https://github.com/tilezen/vector-datasource/blob/82127d1b1040ae6f1b9a38ab8b348cb3b6f97e4f/queries/planet_osm_polygon.jinja2#L17

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, so I have tried reinstall multiple times. After all installation I keep on getting **ImportError: cannot import name DataFetcher** when I run the server. Is it something to do with using the tagged release to install?

Comment: I have been using all the **git checkout** and their corresponding version numbers of each component listed on the documents

Comment: The combo I have been using is vector-datasource v1.4.0, tileserver v2.1.0 and tilequeue v1.9.0. I have checked out using the said version.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem: https://github.com/tilezen/tileserver/issues/115. Now it worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the `clip_factor` parameter.

Here is Mapzen's configuration: https://github.com/tilezen/vector-datasource/blob/e87ac739b3e98f7c5363df3af06944bcec774c1c/queries.yaml#L231

A `clip_factor: 3.0` will clip buildings only when they span more than three tiles.

Comment: Hi, the default is **3.0**, and it is not working for me. If I set it to **10.0** it is the same, if I set it to **0.0** the buildings would disappear

Comment: I have tried directly assign the clip_factor in **vector-datasource/vectordatasource/transform.py** to **3.0**. The result is the same.